# PHP Using class property into another class and use the method again

Tags: php, class, properties

I am not aware of the technical term how to call it.

I have a `base` class which has `$content` property holding entire page array elements. For some constraint, I cannot extends the `base` class

### Base Class

```
/**
 * This is the main class
 *
 * Class base
 */
class base {

    /**
     * Holding entire page data in nested array. Such as nav item, posts, metadata etc. with the respective key => []
     * Example:
     * $this->content = [
     *  'head' => [ // some body elements such as meta tags, title etc],
     *  'body' => [
     *  ]
     * ]
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public $content = [];

    /* This is just for an example of array holding values */

    public function some_methods() {
        // various method to process the $content and return the element
        $this->content = [
            'head' => [ /* some body elements such as meta tags, title etc */ ],
                'body' => [
                    'footer' => [ /* header elements */ ],
                    'nav' => [ /* nav items */ ],
                    'article' => [
                        'text' => [ /* text and title */],
                        'metadata' => [ /* metadata */]
                    ],
                    'footer' => [ /* footer elements */ ]
                ]
            ];
    }

    public function load_navs( $navs ) {
        $one = new one();

        $one->hello($navs);
        // OR
        // some methods has loops in the `base` class
        foreach ( $navs as $key => $value ) {
            // whatever..
            $one->hello($key, $value);
        }

    }

    public function load_footer( $footer ) {
        $two = new two();
        $two->widget($footer);
    }
}
```

What I want to do is to make some more classes to customize some logic of the `base` class `methods`. For that to get a value I need to use `$content` of the `base` class into the another class. They the methods from the newly created classes I will use in the `base` class `methods`

### One

```
/**
 * Class to customize or override base class logic
 * Class one
 */
class one {
    // to do some process I need to access $content from the `base` class. For example

    public function hello($navs){
        // here something to check from `nav`
        // this method I will use in base class
        if ($this->content['nav']['item']['selected']){
            // do the stuff
        }
    }
}
```

### Two

```
/**
 * Class to customize or override base class logic
 * Class two
 */
class two {
    // to do some process I need to access $content from the `base` class. For example

    public function hello($footer){
        // here something to check from `footer`
        // this method I will use in base class
        if ($this->content['footer']['widget']['type'] == 'foo'){
            // do the stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all: Are you really not allowed to extend the Base class? If so and you just want to use the `$content` within the methods in `one` and `two`, you can pass it as a second argument. Please be aware if you want to modify the original `$content` you will have to pass it by reference.

Comment: Why you can't use extends ? And can you use static property ?

Answer (score 2):

If you can't extends your class, you can use static attribute. An static attribute is an attribute link to the class and not to an instantiated object.

[Look at this link for details](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php). I copy past the important informations

> Declaring class properties or methods as static makes them accessible
>   without needing an instantiation of the class.

So you can declare `static $content` in your base Class and use it like : `base::$content;`

```
    class Base {
        public static $content = [];
    }

    class One {
        function foo () {
           var_dump(Base::$content);
        }
    }

    $foo = new One();

    $foo->foo();
```

//show : 
    array (size=0)
      empty

And by convention, your name Classe need to upperCase (Base, One, Two)

EDIT : No Static, No Extends.

/*
    if you can't extends AND you can't use static, you can instancied Base object in you One Class. 
    Like Tobias say in this comment, if you want change the $content for both Base and One, you need pass the var via reference.
    Look at this first example, the base->$content is empty before and after One work. And look at the 2nd example : I get the base content 
    via reference and the content change in both case. 
    My english is probably too poor so I suggest to you to read the doc for reference. 
*/

```
class Base {
    public $content = [];


    function displayContent() {
        var_dump($this->content);
    }

}

class One {

    function displayContent() {

        $base = new Base();

        $base->content = 'toto';

        var_dump($base->content);

    }
}

$base = new Base();
$one = new One();

$one->displayContent();
$base->displayContent();

// $one->content == 'toto'; but $base->content still empty.
```

Now: with reference :

```
class Base {

    public $content = [];

    function displayContent() {
        var_dump($this->content);
    }

}

class One {

    public $content;

    function displayContent() {

        var_dump($this->content);

    }
}

$base = new Base();
$one = new One();

$one->content = &$base->content;
$one->content = 'toto';

$one->displayContent();

$base->displayContent();

// NOW, $one->content == 'toto'; and $base->content = 'toto'
```

Comment: *"For some constraint, I cannot extends the base class"* The OP stated that this is **not** an option to use.

Comment: Yes thank for your reflection. I've add new suggestion (static attribute) but maybe he can't use static too. I've asked to him and I edit my post then he give more explains

Comment: Yeah, static might be a good way to go if the OP is allowed to change the `base` class.

Comment: I am still on mid level of OOP. So will it allow without instantiating the class?

Comment: Thanks.. I am waiting :)

Comment: Finised :). I hope it's good for you. And ty again for Tobias for show me my mistake

Comment: No problem, such things just happen.

Comment: @Xenofexs I appreciate your help but here is another thing. As I mentioned, there is a constraint to modify anything within the `Base` class as it is a system class and cannot change. It's something like WordPress Core `WP_Query` class, and you can't change its property.

Comment: If i'ts core class from framework, I don't understand why you can't extends this your own class ...? For WP, you can entends WP_Query. 
Please say what framework you use and why you can't extends. Wordpress ? Look at hook function (add action from event like new post, create taxo ... etc)
Please edit your anwser

Comment: Edited, again ;). But please explain more if it's not good for you. And read the doc, I'm not an english man ;)

Comment: @Xenofexs Yes, I should be able to extend the Core class too as WP_Query. I am not using any popular framework but something created by one developer. Let me try it to extend it.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below mentioned lines while inherits property of base class.

```
class One extends Base

class Two extends Base
```

Than after you can use the property of base class in child class

Comment: *"For some constraint, I cannot extends the base class"* The OP stated that this is **not** an option to use.